# Select input, ngValue in options differs in Angular 2 component

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-components

When the options of a select input are defined in a template in this way:

```
<select formControlName="gender">
    <option *ngFor="let g of genders" [ngValue]="g.code">{{g.name}}</option>
</select>
```

the control is rendered:

```
<select class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="gender" ng-reflect-name="gender">
    <option ng-reflect-ng-value="0: 71011">Dona</option>
    <option ng-reflect-ng-value="1: 71012">Home</option>
    <option ng-reflect-ng-value="2: 71013">Desconegut</option>
</select>
```

That works well and, for the selected option, **the value is recovered from the FormGroup as a number**.

Now I'm trying to develop a component that loads any parameters list with the same structure (code/name) and for that, I have defined the component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'select[selectLoader]',
    template: `
        <option *ngFor="let parameter of parametersArray" [ngValue]="parameter.code">{{parameter.name}}</option>                `
})
```

In the inner code of the component, the parameters list is loaded properly from the value of the attribute `family` (providing a code for the family of parameters). The difference is that being in both cases the code a number, in that one the component is rendered:

```
<select class="c3 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" family="GENDER" formcontrolname="gender" selectloader="" ng-reflect-name="gender" ng-reflect-family="GENDER">
    <option ng-reflect-ng-value="71011">Dona</option>
    <option ng-reflect-ng-value="71012">Home</option>
    <option ng-reflect-ng-value="71013">Desconegut</option>
</select>
```

In this case, **the value returned by the FormGroup is a string** instead of a number so although the template part for the options is the same it is rendered differently and the returned value doesn't correspond with the `ngValue` type.

In both cases `ngValue` is defined with `[ngValue]="parameter.code"` being `code` a number but in the second one is treated as a string.

Why is that different and how can I do it?

Update: Here is an [example in stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umkxwz). I've discovered that even totally ignores the ngValue and takes content text as value.

Comment: I think the problem is in other parts of your code. If you could create a stackblitz.com reproduction example it would be easy to investigate.

Comment: The rest of the code just have the loading of the parameters list and in both cases `code` is a number.

Comment: "Talk is cheap. Show me the code." Linus Torvalds (2000)

Comment: Now you have an example...

Answer (score 1):

`NgSelectOption` wants to inject `SelectControlValueAccessor` from `@Host()`, but in your case host doesn't provide it.

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/e22f0e9ef32dd162c2ce0c9d17271341ef4c40d9/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.dart#L101-L103

This causes the rest of the `NgSelectOption` directive to behave differently

https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/e22f0e9ef32dd162c2ce0c9d17271341ef4c40d9/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.dart#L103-L133

which results in the behavior you descried.

I haven't found a way to work around.
(My attempt https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p89pvz?file=app/select_loader.component.ts)